# Unity3D Dynamic variable declare

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm having trouble when trying to make a dynamic variable like this example:

```
→ public TYPE_UNKNOW myType;

void Awake(){
//i want to make myType as SpriteRenderer Or Image or int float etc.

}
```

I appreciate all your replies.

Comment: make it object as they all are. But not knowing the type is generally not a good starting case.

Comment: It might also be possible to use `dynamic`. I don't know if that actually works in unity and can't test it right now though.

Comment: Er...just wondering, why do you want a public variable of unknown type at runtime, anyways? What's your use case for this?

Comment: I think `dynamic` is part of Net 4.0 so it will not be available in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an Implicit Type, when you want to do this you only have to declare a **var** type variable. The **var** keyword tells to the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

Example:

```
// i is compiled as an int
var i = 5;

// s is compiled as a string
var s = "Hello";

// a is compiled as int[]
var a = new[] { 0, 1, 2 };

// expr is compiled as IEnumerable<Customer>
// or perhaps IQueryable<Customer>
var expr =
    from c in customers
    where c.City == "London"
    select c;

// anon is compiled as an anonymous type
var anon = new { Name = "Terry", Age = 34 };

// list is compiled as List<int>                             
var list = new List<int>();
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

Comment: Sergio is correct for local variables but you cannot use var for global variables. You could try "object" and see if that works.